# Steroids, Intel framework, phonegap, bootstrap, angularjs...for a hibryd web/mobile crossplatform app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, netbeans, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

[CLARIFIED QUESTION]
Try to imagine that you are building some clone of facebook(we can call it 'clonebook') from scratch, and you are the only developer working on it. To minimize time and efforts you want to do moreless the same coding for the web access and for the installable packages. Here you need to consider two main points, the clonebook use it at the web, on desktops(so we need to consider even internet explorer, firefox, etc...) and mobiles(usually webkit).
Here you dont usually use the camera to upload pictures but the filemanager and you use the emails or alias for your contacts.

The second point is the installable app, where you add the access to the phone camera to upload de picture, plubic news on clonebook in your wall in facebookapp, twitterapp, etc... Also you can add somehow the contacts by phone from your agenda in the phone. I will also add notifications, so is clear that i need to add lines of coding, usin a plugins from cordova, in case of phonegap.

So with this in mind:
1º- If i build clonebook with app framework, how will it looks like in the web in a desktop? Will it look like a supersized mobile app in a desktop browser?
2º- It's all compatible with internet explorer and firefox or just webkit?

The normal answer is bootstrap for webapps, appframe for mobileapps...but in my case where is 50% of each the answer isnt so clear unless you are professional with both technologies. I know the decision will be mine, but I need advices.
Thankyou and I hope you can clarify this a bit more.

PD: We can reduce the list now to:

-Intel framework(counting his IDE, his builder, his wrapper, etc...) + phonegap

-Html5Boilerplate(just a skeleton)+modernizr+bootstrap+jquery(just because is dependency of 
bootstrap)+netbeans(IDE).

-Steroids+AngularJs+Netbeans.(the problem here is that i think that steroids works well just with webkit based browsers...so desktop support can be a problem).

PD2: About Steroids, is a cordoba 2.8 fork optimized and with its own wrapper in the cloud, free of charge for every system and allow unlimited comercial licenses. It also add completely support to angularjs that makes MVC quite easy and without jqueries.

[!CLARIFIED QUESTION]

[OLD QUESTION]I'm working in a master thesis that it's somekind of social network, that I want to be something like facebook oriented, you can access by web, or you can install it and have more functionality.

For the server side I'll work with PHP+PhPixie+MariaDB+NginX.
For the client side I already made some practice with every html5/css/jv framework/jquery out there.
For now, I think the best option It's html5boilerplate+modernizr+twitter bootstrap+jquery+phonegap with Netbeans IDE(everything I want to use should be free comercial license)

But taking now a look I've found few more mobile oriented frameworks that maybe will suit more. Those are the combinations I want you to discuss, if it's better to make a change or just continue as I think. I want some balance between speed, documentation, easy of use, easy of wrapping, bugs, etc...:

- Intel framework(counting his IDE, his builder, his wrapper, etc...).
- Steroids+AngularJs+Netbeans.
- Intel framework + phonegap
- Intel framework + jquery plugin
- Intel framework + jquery plugin + Twitter bootstrap
- Intel framework + jquery plugin + Twitter bootstrap + phonegap

I'm really confuse if I should consider those options instead of my selected one.
I need to point once again that is web/mobile cross-platform, and not just mobile cross. So isnt an option to see a supersized mobile look in the web as opossed to a responsive web.
Thankyou.[!OLD QUESTION]

Comment: I woud say: less is more!

Comment: So will you choose the option Intel Framework? Or you are talking about the stylesheet language?

Comment: When is this thesis due and how well do you understand the technologies (frameworks/toolkits mentioned)!?

Comment: The thesis is already on road, finishing the database model right know, so soon(few weeks) I must start coding. About the techonologies I just know the concepts and easy stuff about all of them like small practices that you can find in google, but no more, so Whatever I choose I'll learn in the way without support apart of internet forums/blogs.